# Ranking functions in order of increasing complexity.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a list of functions here that I need to rank in order of increasing complexity.

They are: n!, $n^2$, 3$n^3$, 1000n + 2, n$\log_{10}(n)$, 20$\log_2(n)$, $3^n$ + $n^2$, $2^n$ + $n^3$

This is how I have ranked them in order of increasing complexity:

20$\log_2(n)$, 1000n + 2, n$\log_{10}(n)$, $n^2$, 3$n^3$, $2^n$ + $n^3$, $3^n$ + $n^2$, n!

Have I ranked them correctly?

Comment: yes, you have ranked them correctly